# Another 'is there a design pattern for this?'

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have two separate classes, ClassA and ClassB, that derive from the same base class, but have different business logic. I need to define a third class, ClassC, that also derives from the same base class. This class will be a combination of the existing two classes, i.e, depending on certain criteria, whenever ClassC's DoSomething() method gets called, I want to call that method from ClassA or ClassB instead (These are not static methods), based on certain criteria. (Note that for every instance of ClassC, the criteria that determines whether I want ClassA or ClassB logic can change). Is there a specific design pattern that could help me get started with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I sounds like you need to look at the State or Strategy pattern. What you basically want is delegation rather than inheritance.

Comment: Same for me. State, because of the dynamic selection, Strategy because of "proxying" behaviour..

Comment: FYI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern IMHO matches quite well, see the graph and "Strategy" interface. IMHO, the object that implements a Strategy may contain dynamically-changing information that determines how to select the proper "concrete" strategies differently on each requests? BTW. In that link there's pretty well explained the difference between Strategy and Bridge. I always tend to mistake them, I think it's worth reading :)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you need to use composition instead of inheritance.
Have a look at Composite Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern
In wikipedia example it is used to implement tree-like strucutre. In your example you don't have tree so instead of iterating children you simply apply your custom logic and call either ClassA or ClassB implementation.